# I have lists as column-values. How do I get each list item into its own row?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c(x,y) | c(a,b) | qwert | character(0) |

I want to unlist the data frame so that the new one looks like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | qwert | N/A |
| y | b | N/A | N/A |

I have tried using `separate_rows` but it comes back with `Error: Incompatible lengths`

Comment: It's difficult to recreate your dataframe structure from this information. Please paste the output of `dput(mydata)` where `mydata` is the dataframe.

Comment: Probably `tidyr::unnest(my_data)`. May need to specify the list columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried this, but it still gave me incompatible lengths error

Comment: Well, if you have a single row has a list of length 2 in one column, and length 3 in another column (for example), then it's not really clear what the result should be. If you can share a reproducible sample of data we can take a look, something like `dput(your_data[example_rows, ])` is the best way to share data, including all class and structure information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, Column1 = c("c(x,y)"), Column2 = c("c(a,b)"), Column3 = c("qwert"), Column4 = c("character(0)"))

df %>% 
  mutate(Column4 = na_if(Column4, "character(0)")) %>% 
  separate_rows(1:2,sep = "\\(|,|\\)") %>% 
  filter(across(1:2, ~ !.x %in% c("c",""))) %>% 
  mutate(Column3 = if_else(row_number() == 1, Column3, NA_character_))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 x       a       qwert   <NA>   
#> 2 y       b       <NA>    <NA>
```